# How to use one property of prototype of a object in another property of the same object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a interface for some of the objects. For this, `Controller` is my interface. In below example `userException` object is used by `projectContainer`'s `test()` function. But at run time an exception is occurred `Cannot read property 'projectContainer' of undefined`. Is there any possible way of using one function inside a another function of the same Object protorype.

```
const Controller = new Function;

//custom exception
Controller.prototype.userException = new Object;
Controller.prototype.userException.createException = function (name, message, htmlMessage) {
  this.name = name;
  this.message = message;
  this.htmlMessage = htmlMessage;
  Error.captureStackTrace(this);
}

//test function of projectContainer object, use createException function
Controller.prototype.projectContainer = new Object;
Controller.prototype.projectContainer.test = function () {
  throw new this.userException.createException('test', 'test', 'test');
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, `Controller` is a function, right?

Comment: yes. i will add that to the code